# How to use a glmnet model as a node model for the mob function (of the R package party)?

Tags: r, glmnet, party

I am using the `mob` function of the R package `party`. My question concerns the `model` parameter of this function.

How can I define a StatModel object (from the package `modeltools`) - let's call it *glmnetModel* -  so that the nodes models of the `mob` estimation are `glmnet` models (more precisely I would like to use the `cv.glmnet` function as the main estimation function in the `fit` slot of *glmnetModel*) ?

One difficulty is to extend correctly the `reweight` function (and maybe the `estfun` and `deviance` functions ?) like it is suggested [here](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/party/vignettes/MOB.pdf) (section 2.1).

Anybody has an idea ?

NB : I have seen some extensions (for SVM : [here](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/%2acheckout%2a/locClass/skel/R/Model_svm.R?revision=108&root=locclass&pathrev=139)) but I am not able to use them correctly.

Thank you very much !

Dominique

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether the inferential framework of the parameter instability tests in the MOB algorithm holds for either glmnet or svm.

The assumption is that the model's objective function (e.g., residual sum of squares or log-likelihood) is additive in the observations and that the corresponding first order conditions are consequently additive as well. Then, under certain weak regularity conditions, a central limit theorem holds for the parameter estimates. This can be extended to a functional central limit theorem upon which the parameter instability tests in MOB are based.

If these assumptions do not hold, the p-values may not be valid and hence may lead to too many or too few splits or a biased splitting variable selection. Whether or not this happens in practice for the models you are interested in, I don't know. You would have to check this - either theoretically (which may be hard) or in simulation studies.

Technically, the reimplementation of `mob()` in the `partykit` package makes it much easier to plug in new models. A lot less glue code (without S4 classes) is necessary now. See `vignette("mob", package = "partykit")` for details.